# MobilePush Marketing Cloud Token Re-registration for existing contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We are working on finalizing our mobile app's compatibility with MobilePush. One thing one of our developer's noticed is that we don't update the Marketing Cloud token registration if the user has already been registered once.

We noticed this because the registration of a specific test user (Android), who registered for push via her testing app, but didn't have her registration show in MC until a day later.

We were wondering if there is any kind of issue from the SF side, perhaps something API related, if we register the device for push every time the user opens up the app (if all conditions to stay opted in are still met)?

We are of course open to other solutions here if the registration getting delayed is being caused by something else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. We reached out to SF support and after a bit of digging they determined there should be no issue with these more frequent registration call requests as there is a limit of one call per a minute.

We have since applied the change to our builds. While other issues are still being tested, it appears this change should cause no harm.